# How do I replace the Linux Mint partition with Ubuntu without harming my Windows 10 partition?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows-10

I have a Linux Mint partition on my windows 10 laptop that a friend set up for me a while back to try Linux. Mint played weirdly with my system putting more strain on it than windows 10 did somehow so I just left it to sit there while continuing to use Windows.

I am interested in trying Ubuntu, but I can't just ask my friend to do it this time. I have been trying to look up tutorials or guides, but there are surprisingly few and the ones I have found imply it is easy to accidentally wipe out your windows partition.

I have a bare minimum of Linux knowledge. I have played around in Linux a tiny bit, and know how to use a bootable USB on a system that can just be wholesale overwritten. But when it comes to the partitions and how you would replace them it seems foreign to me.

If nothing else I'd like to find what resources would help someone who has no idea what they are looking at, and I apologize if this is written poorly. This is my first post on the forum.

Comment: Your question has already been asked - and answered.  See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/258842/replacing-mint-with-ubuntu-on-a-dual-boot-laptop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download 18.04 .iso and use Etcher or Rufus in Windows to create a bootable USB thumb drive and restart the PC. Ubuntu will load and ask you to "Try Ubuntu" or "Install", you can select Install.

Follow the installation as normal until you reach the part asking you about partitions and select "Something Else" like here: 
[image]

On the next page you will be shown the partitions:

[image]

- Double click the Linux Mint partition
- Select Ext4 journaling file system
- Check Format the partition
- Select `/` for the mount point