# Ubuntu Partition Freezes a minute or 2 after logging in

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, nvidia, laptop, asus

I asked how to safely go about replacing my linux mint partition a friend set up, and followed the answer given to me here:
[How do I replace the Linux Mint partition with Ubuntu without harming my Windows 10 partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1078747/how-do-i-replace-the-linux-mint-partition-with-ubuntu-without-harming-my-windows)

Since trying Ubuntu without installing via bootable USB was working swimmingly I thought there would be no harm in replacing the mint partition using the helpful answer mentioned previously. Sadly it seems the Ubuntu partition is pretty much unusable.

The moment I log in to Ubuntu it simply stops after about a minute. No crashes, errors, or black screens. It just refuses to take input of any kind. Luckily the Windows 10 partition is fine and I can easily boot into either via grub2.

I am not sure what could have happened other than the partition screen displayed during install that is shown in the helpful answer was different than mine. Mine had more than 4 extra partitions compared to his, one labeled efi. In retrospect I should have questioned that more.

**My laptop**

- Asus VivoBook Pro 17,
- 1TB hard drive and 256GB SSD,
- i7-8550U mobile processor,
- 16GB RAM
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 graphics card

I am not sure what other info would be useful but I'll provide anything I can.

**EDIT:**

I am a bit more confused than before. After numerous tries just restarting my laptop to try suggestions without it freezing before I could even get through the "Welcome to Ubuntu" setup I chose not to send error info instead of the default on my last restart.

For some reason that stopped the freezing until I allowed some downloaded updates to install and chose to restart, which immediately froze Ubuntu up to where I needed force shutdown my laptop. It seems that whenever I try to normally shutdown or restart Ubuntu it freezes now.

The following is output from ls -al /var/crash:

**ls -al /var/crash**

**total 8**

**drwxrwsrwt  2 root whoopsie 4096 Jul 24 22:09 .**

**drwxr-xr-x 14 root root     4096 Jul 24 22:14 ..**

Comment: If you're using the Nvidia proprietary drivers I suggest you disable them.

Comment: Have you installed any GNOME extensions? If so, it's probably one of those. Go to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ and disable them all, and see if that fixes it. Report back to @heynnema.

Comment: @heynnema I was frustrated since I could not manage to actually attempt either of your suggestions. Each time I could not even make it through the "Welcome to Ubuntu" setup pages before it would freeze. Then on my last restart I chose not to send error info on a whim, and for some reason it seems to be working fine at the moment. I was curious if you had any idea why this might be the case?

Comment: I only offered one suggestion :-) It sounds like this is a new/fresh install. It sounds like something is crashing at boot/login time. Edit your question to include the output of `ls -al /var/crash`.

Comment: Oh, I was referring to yours and Kristopher Ives suggestions. :)

Comment: @heynnema added the command output to the question.

Comment: @HopefulNewb see my partial answer, and report back.

Answer (score 0):

## Incomplete answer...

**1. Lets first check your file system for errors.**

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

If for some reason you can't do the above...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted` and determine which /dev/sdaX is your Ubuntu EXT4 partition
- quit `gparted`
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdaX` # replacing X with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**2. Boot to the Ubuntu Live USB or DVD, and see if it's stable.**

Report back to @heynnema in the comments.

Comment: I did as you said. I ran the fsck command and it found no errors before going back to command input, then since it took me a second to realize it finished it said something about timeout not being able to access certain partitions like efi. I ran it again to be safe and it gave nothing, so I typed the reboot command. And it hung so I had to force shutdown the laptop again.

Comment: @HopefulNewb  I need the exact error message that you saw during the fsck. Did you try step #2? I assume that it worked fine. Once booted to the USB flash drive, start the `Disks` application, go to the hamburger icon and select SMART Data & Tests. Observe the drive summary, and run the tests. Report back.